# $Env:ComputerName doesnt work with powershell Send-MailMessage in batch file

Tags: powershell, email, batch-file

After a lot of errors and edits I got the Send-MailMessage to work through a command prompt.  Below iteration sends out the emails perfect.

```
powershell Send-MailMessage -From " `<user@domain>`" -To " `<user@domain.com>`" -Subject 'Some subject goes here' -Body 'Some body with alert regarding Host: $env:computername. List of deleted files is attached.' -Attachments 'C:\somefile.txt' -Priority High -dno onSuccess, onFailure -SmtpServer 'smtp.domain.com'
```

However, this does not fetch the `computername` in the body. I have tried running this command in powershell directly and it works with the computername variable in body.

> To get it to simply send out mails, I have already tried doing
>   `powershell -command "command"` or `powershell -command "{command}` or
>   `powershell -command "& {command}"` and so on and it doesnt even send
>   out emails.

As I am now successful sending out emails, I need to have the Computername inside the body text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command line in the question and your own answer relies on the fact that powershell currently has the default (position 0) argument `-Command`,
but as this changes from `PowerShell 6.0.0beta3` on to `-File`

- you should explicitly use at least `-C` as the shortest
  abbreviviation for `-Command`.
- to speed up execution I'd use the additionl parameters `-NoProfile` or short `-NoP` and `-NonInteractive` or `-NonI`
- to stop cmd from trying to interpret any parameters/arguments you should double quote them all - and escape any necessary inner double quotes with a backslash `\"` while also replacing double quotes with single ones if ever  possible.

So I'd suggest:

```
powershell -NoP -NonI -C "Send-MailMessage -From \"SomeWeb-Prod@domain.com\" -To \"fromuser@domain.com\" -Subject 'Some notification for SomeWeb-Prod' -Body 'Some Alert for Host: %computername% with IP: %NetworkIP% at %time%. details in attached file.' -Attachments 'C:\somefile.txt' -Priority High -dno onFailure -SmtpServer 'smtp.domain.com'"
```

Or, (as you partly  discovered  yourself):

```
powershell -NoP -NonI -C "Send-MailMessage -From 'SomeWeb-Prod@domain.com' -To 'fromuser@domain.com' -Subject 'Some notification for SomeWeb-Prod' -Body 'Some Alert for Host: %computername% with IP: %NetworkIP% at %time%. details in attached file.' -Attachments 'C:\somefile.txt' -Priority High -dno onFailure -SmtpServer 'smtp.domain.com'"
```

Answer (score 3):

Use double quotes around the argument value to have variables contained expanded.

I.e.:

```
-Body "Some body with alert regarding Host: **$env:computername**. ..."
```

Relevant [reading](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules).

Comment: It din't.  I ended up using `%computername%`  batch variable and that works perfect.  Not sure how that happens in a powershell command.

Comment: You would have to show the source of your batch file then. Probably there is something else wrong.

Answer (score 0):

`"$env:computername"` doesnot work for me. It simply prints it as $env:computername

`%computername%` worked.

Here's what's working for me right now.

```
powershell Send-MailMessage -From " `<user@domain.com>`" -To " `<user@domain.com>`" -Subject 'Some subject goes here' -Body 'Some body with alert regarding Host: %computername%. Some file is attached.' -Attachments 'C:\somefile.txt' -Priority High -dno onSuccess, onFailure -SmtpServer 'smtp.domain.com'
```

**Update:**

The above command worked on Win7 fine, but gave errors on server 2012.  Finally this is what worked on win 2012

```
powershell "Send-MailMessage -From "SomeWeb-Prod@domain.com" -To "fromuser@domain.com" -Subject 'Some notification for SomeWeb-Prod' -Body 'Some Alert for Host: %computername% with IP: %NetworkIP% at %time%. details in attached file.' -Attachments 'C:\somefile.txt' -Priority High -dno onFailure -SmtpServer 'smtp.domain.com'"
```

Answer (score 0):

It works for me, by using double quotes around variables.

I am using batch script to call powershell Send-MailMessage

> Batch Script:send_email.bat

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe  -windowstyle hidden -command 'E:\path\send_email.ps1
```

> Pwershell Script send_email.ps1

```
Send-MailMessage -From "noreply@$env:computername" -To '<target_email@example.com>' -Subject 'Blah Blah' -SmtpServer  'smtp.domain.com'  -Attachments 'E:\path\file.log' -BODY "Blah Blah on Host: $env:computername "
```